# AWK program that can read a second file either from a file specified on the command line or from data received via a pipe

Tags: awk

I have an AWK program that does a join of two files, `file1` and `file2`. The files are joined based on a set of columns. I placed the AWK program into a bash script that I named `join.sh`. See below. Here is an example of how the script is executed:

```
./join.sh '1,2,3,4' '2,3,4,5' file1 file2
```

That says this: Do a join of `file1` and `file2`, using columns (fields) 1,2,3,4 of `file1` and columns (fields) 2,3,4,5 of `file2`.

That works great.

Now what I would like to do is to filter `file2` and pipe the results to the join tool:

```
./fetch.sh ident file2 | ./join.sh '1,2,3,4' '2,3,4,5' file1
```

`fetch.sh` is a bash script containing an AWK program that fetches the rows in `file2` with primary key `ident` and outputs to stdout the rows that were fetched.

Unfortunately, that pipeline is not working. I get no results.

Recap: I want the join program to be able to read the second file either from a file that I specify on the command line or from data received via a pipe. How to do that?

Here is my bash script, named `join.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

awk  -v f1cols=$1  -v f2cols=$2 '
BEGIN                     { FS=OFS="\t" 
                            m=split(f1cols,f1,",")
                            n=split(f2cols,f2,",")
                          }
                          { sub(/\r$/, "") }
NR == 1                   { b[0] = $0 } 
(NR == FNR) && (NR > 1)   { idx2=$(f2[1])
                            for (i=2;i<=n;i++)
                                idx2=idx2 $(f2[i]) 
                            a[idx2] = $0
                            next 
                          }
(NR != FNR) && (FNR == 1) { print $0, b[0] }
FNR > 1                   { idx1=$(f1[1])
                            for (i=2;i<=m;i++)
                                idx1=idx1 $(f1[i])
                            for (idx1 in a)
                                print $0, a[idx1]
                          }' $3 $4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is 'correct' as you haven't provided any example input and expected output, but does using `-` to signify stdin work for your use-case? E.g.

```
cat file1
1 2 3 4
AA BB CC DD
AA EE FF GG

cat file2
1 2 3 4
AA ZZ YY XX
AA 11 22 33

./join.sh '1' '1' file1 file2
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
AA ZZ YY XX AA BB CC DD
AA ZZ YY XX AA EE FF GG
AA 11 22 33 AA BB CC DD
AA 11 22 33 AA EE FF GG

cat file2 | ./join.sh '1' '1' file1 -
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
AA ZZ YY XX AA BB CC DD
AA ZZ YY XX AA EE FF GG
AA 11 22 33 AA BB CC DD
AA 11 22 33 AA EE FF GG
```

Answer (score 2):

> be able to read(...)from data received via a pipe

GNU `AWK` does support [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html) consider following simple example

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="seq 7";while((cmd | getline) > 0){print $1*7};close(cmd)}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
7
14
21
28
35
42
49
```

Explanation: I process output of `seq 7` command (numbers from 1 to 7 inclusive, each on separate line), body of while is executed for each line of `seq 7` output, fields are set like for normal processing.